# Chrome automatically opens SpreadsheetML in new tab as XML

Tags: xml, google-chrome, attachment, content-disposition, spreadsheetml

Since version 33.0.1750.117 of Google Chrome we experience problems with SpreadsheetML from our system. Normally we could force the download of the XML with the following instructions in our HTTP server.

```
<Files *.xml>
 Header Always Set Content-Disposition attachment
 AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xml
</Files>
```

However, the SpreadsheetML is now opened in a new tab with this message:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

After the update to this version we had a couple of problems that we could solve ourselves, but this one remains. We already checked whether Windows 7 still associated the .xml extension with Excel. That is still the case.

The user now has to right click the dowloaded file and choose 'open with system viewer' in order to open the file with Excel.

Who can tell me what else to do?

Comment: This appears to be a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346359) with Chrome that causes this. Once fixed on their side, it should solve your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only remedy I have found so far is to change the extension of the file we are generating to .xls (assuming you are able).

This is not ideal, as upon opening the file the user is prompted with

> The file you are trying to open, 'name.ext', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

In our case however this annoyance is the lesser of evils; our users are totally bewildered by Chrome's new treatment of .xml but seem comfortable clicking 'Yes' to the above prompt.